# Error: too few arguments to function 'twice'

Tags: c

I'm new to C and I'm having some problems in this code where I'm getting these errors.

```
sum2.c: In function 'main':
sum2.c:22:6: warning: 'z' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
  int z = twice(x, z);
```

On my code I needed to add a fuction twice, which, given a number, calculates its double, using only the elementary operations and the sum function. And I don't know if the way I put the function is correct.

```c
//USER
//3532

#include <stdio.h>

int sum(int x, int y){
    return y == 0 ? x : sum(x+1, y-1);
}

int twice(int x, int z){
    z = x * x;
    return 0;
}

int main(void){
    int x;
    int y;
    scanf("%d%d", &x, &y);
    int z = twice(x, z);
    printf("%d\n", z);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Twice takes two parameters, `x` and `z`. You're only calling it with one argument when you write `twice(x * x)`.

Comment: You also have infinite recursion: `twice` calls itself unconditionally.

Comment: Why does `twice` need two arguments if it's just supposed to calculate the double of a number?

Comment: You’ve declared the function as one taking two arguments. You call it with only one from inside itself. What exactly are you trying to do here? Shouldn’t it be just `return x*x` and there’s no need for the second argument?

Comment: You need to use the fact that the double of x is x+x

Comment: The `twice` function unconditionally returns 0, which doesn't make much sense.... Also what is _"using only the elementary operations"_ is suppsed to mean?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Ye i declared as taking two arguments which wasn't what i was supposed to do. I just wanted to double the end-result using the fuction twice, since on my assigment i needed to use both sum and twice functions.

Comment: @Jabberwocky On my assigment, i only was permitted to use elementary operations as you see on the function sum.

Comment: @vunax then what's wrong with `return x+y;` in `sum`?

Comment: Wait, did you fix the code in the question? Now the question doesn't make sense. Where's the compilation error?

Comment: @giusti Yes, Barmar helped me fix the code, since this is my first post on stack overflow should i update the post?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a Q&A repository. People come here, read your question and see if they have the same problem. Then they read the answers. If you "fix" the problem after someone answers, then what will people be looking for in your question?

Comment: Just mark an answer as accepted and leave the question unchanged. Only change the question if it was not clear the first time you wrote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instructions say that `twice` is "given a number", but you've defined it as taking two numbers. It only needs one parameter.

And you're supposed to use your `sum()` function. There's no need to multiply `x*x` (that's the square of the number, not twice the number), nor is there any point in assigning a variable in the `return` statement.

You only need to read one number as input to test this.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sum(int x, int y)
{
    return y == 0 ? x : sum(x+1, y-1);
}

int twice(int x)
{
    return sum(x, x);
}

int main(void)
{
    int x;
    int w;
    scanf("%d", &x);
    int w = twice(x);
    printf("%d\n", w);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the point of `return y == 0 ? x : sum(x+1, y-1);`? Why not just `return x + y;`?

Comment: Ahhhhhh i just saw earlier i was asking for 2 numbers, but just asking is it possible in c with the function twice to input 2 number then double the result of that 2 numbers?

Comment: @Ayxan Apparently the only "elementary operations" they're allowed to use are just adding and subtracting 1. So it uses recursion to add more.

Comment: @vunax What do you mean by "double the result of that 2 numbers"? You mean `twice(sum(x, y))`?

Comment: @Ayxan , On my assigment i was not permitted to change the sum function. So i had to work on the code with the sum fuction like that.

Comment: @Barmar Yes. That's what i meant.

Comment: Then that's what you can write. But the question was about fixing `twice()`, anything else is extra.

Comment: @Barmar hmm, ok. Thanks for everything.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description the function `twice` should accept only one argument.
So this function definition

```
int twice(int x, int z)
{
    z = x * x;
    return 0;
}
```

does not make sense. Moreover the function always returns 0.

Also take into account that the type `int` is a signed integer type. The user can input a negative number. In this case your function sum will yield a wrong result.

The sum of two integers of the type `int` can be too big to fit in an object of the type `int`. That is there can be for example an overflow.

The functions can be defined the following way as it is shown in a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

long long int sum( int x, int y )
{
    return y == 0 ? ( long long int )x
                  : sum( y < 0 ? x - 1 : x + 1, y < 0 ? y + 1 : y - 1 );
}

long long int twice( int x)
{
    return sum( x, x );
}

int main(void) 
{
    int x;

    printf( "Enter a number: " );
    scanf("%d", &x);

    long long int result  = twice( x );

    printf("The sum is %lld\n", result );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
Enter a number: -5
The sum is -10
```

Or

```
Enter a number: 5
The sum is 10
```

Comment: What i was trying to do on my code was using the fuction sum and fuction twice to get the double of a number i put. Also the return 0 on function twice was my bad i figured later it would be always the result 0.

Comment: @vunax See my code. It returns a correct result not only when the user inputs a non-negative number but also when the used inputs a negative number. Otherwise your program will be invalid.

Comment: Hmm i see, there some things i don't know on your code like `long long` and `%lld`. I mean i didn't learned it yet.

Comment: @vunax long long int is a type that can hold more big numbers than the type int. %lld is used to output values of variables of the type long long int.